# Suddenly, started getting "ERROR 2026 (HY000): Unknown SSL error"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos, mariadb-10.5, centos-7

MariaDB instance has been running well for ages, and suddenly, starting about 30 minutes ago, my apps get this error trying to connect:

```
# mysql
ERROR 2026 (HY000): Unknown SSL error
```

My certs have been always under "/etc/my.cnf.d/certs/", generated by LetsEncrypt.
They expire on 2021-11-04, last modified date 2021-08-06.

my.cnf:

```
ssl_cert                        = "/etc/my.cnf.d/certs/fullchain.pem"
ssl_key                         = "/etc/my.cnf.d/certs/privkey.pem"
```

Looking at the logs, there's nothing that hints anything.
The latest log there is about "InnoDB: Online DDL", long ago.

No recent yum system updates.

**How can I investigate the cause of this problem?**
From the research I made, the questions are due to setup issues, while in my case it's been working since always, but **"suddenly" failed, and I can't see what changed**.

--

UPDATE: I wonder if this related,

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/help-thread-for-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/149190

> On September 30 2021, there will be a small change in how older browsers and devices trust Let’s Encrypt certificates.
> (...)
> DST Root CA X3 will expire on September 30, 2021.

I wonder how can I make MariaDB trust ISRG Root X1!

Comment: What's the client OS?

Comment: It's localhost to localhost. I wonder if this related,

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/help-thread-for-dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/149190

> "On September 30 2021, there will be a small change in how older browsers and devices trust Let’s Encrypt certificates." "DST Root CA X3 will expire on September 30, 2021." ---- 
I wonder how can I make MariaDB trust ISRG Root X1, instead of DST Root CA X3!

Answer (score 1):

Alright... for those who have the same problem,

Run this if you haven't yet:

`# yum update ca-certificates`

If you get `No packages marked for update`, it may have been already run automatically - in my case, it was on Sep 24:
`Sep 24 05:00:16 Updated: ca-certificates-2021.2.50-72.el7_9.noarch`

And then run in your MySQL instance:

`> FLUSH SSL;`

This resolved my problem!